# Dynamic index names

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-opensearch-connector

I'm currently working on transferring my data from the S3 data source to OpenSearch utilizing AWS Glue ETL jobs. The process is running smoothly; however, I'm facing a challenge in populating data into multiple OpenSearch indices. Specifically, I need the index name to correspond to one of the field values in my source JSON files. Could someone assist me in resolving this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To address your challenge, you can partition your data based on the index name field value and utilize bulk insert for better performance. Additionally, don't forget to enable compression during the writing process to improve write efficiency. I suggest you to use SDK directly.

If you want use the connector you can:

```
    split_dataframes = {}
    for row in df.select("index").distinct().collect():
        col_value = row["index"]
        split_dataframes[col_value] = df.filter(df["index"] == col_value)
    
    # Write to opensearch
    for key, value in split_dataframes.items():
        glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
           frame = value,
           connection_type = "opensearch",
           connection_options = {
              "opensearch.resource": key,
              "connectionName": "Opensearch connection"
            }
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for responding @Luca, I'm not sure how can I pass the partition key for index name, I'm using the default OpenSearch connector with the following `connection_options` `{"opensearch.resource": "test_index", "pushdown": "true", "connectionName": "Opensearch connection"}`

Comment: I'm looking for options to send dynamic index names (in place of `test_index`) based on my source data

Comment: Thanks, @Luca! I've successfully populated data into multiple dynamic indices. However, the job encountered an error: `Error Category: UNCLASSIFIED_ERROR; An error occurred while calling o8372.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Could not write all entries for bulk operation [1/1]. Error sample (first [5] error messages)`. Interestingly, the same data set worked correctly with the default OpenSearch connector when using a hardcoded index name. Any thoughts?

Comment: I believe it is something related to the DataFrame to DynamicFrame convertion. I have updated my original question with the old code which is working fine, here is the current code that causing the above error:

Comment: `df = ChangeSchema_node1708535985382.toDF()
...

for key, value in split_dataframes.items():
    glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        frame=DynamicFrame.fromDF(value, glueContext, "test_nest"),
        connection_type="opensearch",
        connection_options={
            "opensearch.resource": "glue_"+key.lower(),
            ..
        },
    )`